# How to checkout only the changes of a given tag?

Tags: git

Lets assume, I've added and committed the following files and created a tag 'TAGv1'

```
b.txt ---> TAGv1  -->  commit-id-1
a.txt
```

Again I added and committed the following files

```
d.txt ---> TAGv2  -->  commit-id-2
c.txt
```

When I say, 'git checkout TAGv2' it checkout all the 4 files (a,b,c and d) which is EXPECTED

However, is it possible to 'checkout' only 'c.txt and d.txt' using 'TAGv2'?

I understand this won't be the case in real-time.  However, wanted to see whether such option / feature exists in GIT

Answer (score 0):

To only get the changes of commit-id-2. I would use `git cherry-pick commit-id-2`.

Comment: Please post an example for 'HEAD of commit-id-2'

Comment: @SathishKumar, I mean your SHA number (it should be your commit-id-2). e.g. git cherry-pick c90fd66.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagrams don't make sense to me, so I am not really sure what you intend.  It's worth noting that in Git, a tag name is just a name for a commit hash.  This makes tag names and branch names *almost* the same thing: a branch name is *also* a name for a commit hash.  The key difference between a tag name and a branch name is that a branch name is *meant* to "move"—to change its underlying hash ID over time—and a tag name is *not* supposed to move in this way.  In fact, a branch name is so strongly meant to move that Git will move it *automatically*, when you use `git checkout <branch-name>` and then subsequent `git commit` commands.

---

With all that out of the way, there are several ways to inspect or extract any particular file(s) from any particular commit(s).  For instance, suppose we have this:

- Branch name `master` points to commit `deadcab`.
- Tag name `v1.3` points to commit `1c0ffee`.
- There is no name for commit `fadbead` but you see it in your `git log` history.

You would like to view file `sandwich` in commit `1c0ffee`, aka `v1.3`:

```
git show v1.3:sandwich
git show 1c0ffee:sandwich
```

will both do this.

You would like to get onto branch `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

will do this.  Now you would like to extract the version of file `cucumber` from `fadbead` and make a *new* commit on `master`, so that `master` maps to this new commit:

```
git checkout fadbead -- cucumber
git commit
```

The `git checkout` step is somewhat like the `git show` command, with two differences:

- It writes the checked-out file *to* the work-tree.  This means that the work-tree version of file `cucumber` now matches the `fadbead` version of file `cucumber`.
- It writes the checked-out file *through* the index.  This means the `git commit` above uses the updated file, *as if you had run `git add` on it*.

Now that `master` points to a new commit, you decide you want the file `cucumber` in your *work-tree* to be set back to the way it was in `deadcab`, i.e., the previous `master` commit; but you don't want this `git add`-ed this time.  You can use:

```
git show deadcab:cucumber > cucumber
```

or:

```
git show master~1:cucumber > cucumber
```

to get the previous version back into your work-tree, *without* writing it to the index (i.e., without staging it for the next commit).  The primary difference between this and the `git checkout commit -- path` method is that `git checkout` version writes it to the index.

(There is a secondary difference as well: if you have end of line or smudge filter attributes that apply to the file, the `git checkout` method applies them, while the `git show` method does not.)